# OpenVPN server with BIND 9 DNS on AWS. Linux client cannot resolve host names

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, debian, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server set up and working on an AWS Debian instance. It works as it should but I want to push DNS queries to Linux clients from BIND 9 which is on the same server as OpenVPN. All seems to look good when I connect to the server. I have the appropriate lines in the `client.opvn` file e.g.:

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

When I check `resolve.conf` on the client machine machine the DNS server address is what I think it should be. E.g. to the IP address of `tun0` on the OpenVPN server `10.8.93.1`.

The DNS lookup works on the server when using this address. But on the client machine it will not.

My `named.conf.options` file looks like this:

```
acl goodclients {
        172.31.18.0/24;
        10.8.93.0/24;
        127.0.0.1;
        localhost;
        localnets;
};

options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        recursion yes;
        allow-query { goodclients; };

        forwarders {
                91.239.100.100;
                89.233.43.71;
        };
        forward only;

        dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

My OpenVPN `server.conf` is as follows:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

comp-lzo
keepalive 10 120

persist-key
persist-tun
user nobody
group nogroup

chroot /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/crl.jail
crl-verify crl.pem

ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh1024.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ta.key 0
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt

ifconfig-pool-persist /var/lib/openvpn/server.ipp
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/server.ccd
status /var/log/openvpn/server.log
verb 4

# virtual subnet unique for openvpn to draw client addresses from
# the server will be configured with x.x.x.1
# important: must not be used on your network
server 10.8.93.0 255.255.255.0

# configure clients to route all their traffic through the vpn
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.93.1"
#push "redirect-gateway def1"


#logs
log-append  openvpn.log
verb 5
```

So on the server I can issue this command with success:

```
dig @10.8.93.1 google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> @10.8.93.1 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 35943
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 11, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     251 IN  A   173.194.112.201
google.com.     251 IN  A   173.194.112.206
google.com.     251 IN  A   173.194.112.192
google.com.     251 IN  A   173.194.112.193
google.com.     251 IN  A   173.194.112.194
google.com.     251 IN  A   173.194.112.195
google.com.     251 IN  A   173.194.112.196
google.com.     251 IN  A   173.194.112.197
google.com.     251 IN  A   173.194.112.198
google.com.     251 IN  A   173.194.112.199
google.com.     251 IN  A   173.194.112.200

;; Query time: 130 msec
;; SERVER: 10.8.93.1#53(10.8.93.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Nov  7 00:50:59 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 204
```

But on the client machine it will not work when connected to the VPN server.

Can anyone tell me where I am stumbling here, and what am I missing?

Comment: I forgot to mention, I can ping 10.8.93.1 on the client machine without any issues.

Comment: Can you include the `dig` output from a client where it does not work?

Comment: When I do "dig @10.8.93.1 Google.com" I get a time out on the client.  When I do "dig Google.com"  I get the following output. http://pastebin.com/cdY4TWqw

Comment: Routing table from ec2 can be found here http://pastebin.com/VkMMUDjM and rooting table from client when  connected to vpn can be found here http://pastebin.com/Ej7tBqgy

Comment: Make sure your bind server is listening on the tunnel interface (should be tun0 in your case).